# How to fill my array from another class?(Java)

Tags: java, arrays, class

This is my program that makes some calculations to a numbers into the array named "initialMarks". However I would like to fill the initialMarks array from another class using scanner.Could you help me to figure it out how to do that? Is it possible to outprint the result array "result" in a third class?

```
public class testingN
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
           int [] initialMarks = new int [4];
           int [] result = new int [6];
           result[0] = computedMarks(initialMarks[0], initialMarks[1])[0];
           result[1] = computedMarks(initialMarks[2], initialMarks[3])[1];

            for(int i=0; i< result.length; i++)
                  System.out.println(result[i]);
    }

    public static int [] computedMarks(int mark1, int mark2) 
    {   
        int [] i= new int [6];
            for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++)
        {                   
              if ((mark1 < 35 && mark2 > 35) || (mark1 > 35 && mark2 < 35))
              {
                i[j] = 35;
              }
              else
              {
                i[j] = (mark1 * mark2);
              }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say using the scanner do you mean user input? if so do you have any of that code already?

Comment: Uhm, sorry, no I know how to use the scanner( yes user input ) but when i try to fill the array from another class nothing happens :S

Answer (score 0):

```
public class testingN
{
    static int [] result = new int [6];
    static int [] initialMarks = new int [4];

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
```

Declaring `result` as class member (global variable) and being `static` should help your cause

**Example: using from another class**

```
public class AnotherClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // example
        testingN.result[0] = 4;

        System.out.println(testingN.result[0]);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Run the code below [Here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php).  You'll see it works just fine.

```
class testingN
{
    static int [] result = new int [6];
    static int [] initialMarks = new int [4];
}

public class AnotherClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // example
        testingN.result[0] = 4;

        System.out.println(testingN.result[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: when I make initialmarks a global variable and i try to input some value into initialMarks[0]; and then outprinnt it its 0 :( i think its not working or ?

Comment: Works fine for me. I just tested it out.  How are you using `initialMarks` in another class?  You have to make sure you always use the class name when referencing it `testingN.initialMarks[?]`

Comment: thank you, this helped a lot ! If i have another question can I write a PM to you ? Just to avoid spamming

Comment: I don't think that have PMs here. Please accept answer if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your other class can have a method that returns a stream, and you can feed that into your Scanner's constructor.

In your other class's String getInitialMarks() method:

```
// Generate a string with all the "marks" as "stringWithMarks", separated by "\n" characters
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( stringWithMarks.getBytes( "UTF-8" ) );
return is;
```

Then in your first class, otherClass:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(otherClass.getInitialMarks());
```

And proceed to read in the marks as if it were user input.